# Finding the closed form for a double integral expression?

Tags: analysis, closed-form

I derived the following expression in my analysis

$$
C = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{r_{max}} \log_{2}\left( 1 + \frac{k \lambda^2}{N(4\pi)^2(h^2+d^2+r^2+2rd\cos(\varphi))}\right)rdrd\varphi.
$$

Unfortunately, this seems to be where my abilities end. Could anyone help me in deriving an approximate closed form expression for this expression if obtainable. I had a thought about Chebyshev-Gauss quadrature approximation, but, I don't know how to apply it here.

Comment: I've got a closed form of the inner integral, wrt $r$, using *Mathematica* but it is very ugly and the outer integral gives no result. If you send me the values of the parameters I could try to find an approximate value. Do you mind to add *where* this integral comes from?

Comment: Thanks Raffaele. Although the parameters are variables, typical values could be defined as follows. $N = 10^{-9}$, $h = 20$, $d = 40$, $r_{max} = 10$, $k=3000$, $\varphi = 35$-deg.

The expression comes from analysis of a total gain expected over an ellipse. It is something specific to a system I am working on. $r$ in the expression is the distance of an arbitrary point from the centre of the ellipse.